# Error 403 is showing when i am trying to find data of stocks using IEX CLOUD

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import pandas as pd 
import requests 
import xlsxwriter
import math 
import csv
```

```
alpha = 'my api test key'
symbol = 'AAPL'
api_url = f'https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/{symbol}/quote?token={alpha}'
data = requests.get(api_url)
print(data)
```

```
output: ERROR 403
```

I expected data of AAPL stocks, but its showing 403 error in output

Comment: Check your API key

Comment: You know the sandbox is deprecated?

Comment: wait what its deprecated ?
Can u suggest me an alternative if u know any, it would be great 
thanks for the reply tho